XLOOKUP, INDIRECT, CONCATENATE, and other misadventures in file referencing
I have several file paths I need to adjust dynamically.
Parts of the file path change based on year and month.  I have named cells assigned for the various components and have attempted to use concat, concatenate, indirect, and straight "&" strings, but I just get an #N/A returned.
In the formula breakdown it seems to process into the correct string, but just doesn't function.
Here is what the finished file path should look like, with a working example:
=XLOOKUP(
Q29,
'O:\Operational Excellence\Reporting\Metrics\2024\09. September\Defect Rate\[7-2024 Tracking Report - Final.xlsx]Ops Data'!$A$8:$A$11,
'O:\Operational Excellence\Reporting\Metrics\2024\09. September\Defect Rate\[7-2024 Tracking Report - Final.xlsx]Ops Data'!$F$8:$F$11
)  

Here is a try of making it dynamic, where I am getting #N/A:
=XLOOKUP(
Q29,
CONCAT("'O:\Operational Excellence\Reporting\Metrics\",year,"\",monthnum," ",month,"\Defect Rate\[",defectmonth," Tracking Report - Final.xlsx]Ops Data'!$A$8:$A$11"),
CONCAT("'O:\Operational Excellence\Reporting\Metrics\",year,"\",monthnum," ",month,"\Defect Rate\[",defectmonth," Tracking Report - Final.xlsx]Ops Data'!$F$8:$F$11")
)

I have provided a screenshot of the Function Step Through for this formula: Step Through
Should I be wrapping the concat in some kind of formatting function?  I am open to using INDIRECT and having the file paths built out on my backend sheet where I keep my variables and other behind the scenes stuff, but I feel I would run into the same problem.
I can't find anything wrong with the way it evaluates, so I cannot problem solve the issue any further.
Please let me know if you have any questions or I need to explain something further.  I'm sure this has been asked before but I couldn't find my specific issue, just a lot of people saying to try what I already have done.
Thanks again for any help you can provide.
I have attempted using INDIRECT and having fields in the behind the scenes sheet I have, CONCAT, CONCATENATE, as well as "xxx" & VARIABLE & "xxx" formatting.
I want to be able to simply update the named items to the new month and have the file paths redirect to the new data files.  We already have uniform naming conventions, and I know the data is clean because when I make a static reference it works.

As soon as you start building a reference by concatenation you need INDIRECT which doesn't work across workbooks. Either move the sheet to this workbook to use INDIRECT or use VBA. Either way, you have shared to little information. Also, names like Year, Month ... are also well-known Excel functions and you should consider changing them. They might work but why poke the bear.

Looking at your concat it's not the same string. Your second string is O:\Operational Excellence\Reporting\Metrics\202409 September\Defect Rate[7-2024 Tracking Report - Final.xlsx]Ops Data'!$A$8:$A$11 and your first string O:\Operational Excellence\Reporting\Metrics\2024\09. September\Defect Rate[7-2024 Tracking Report - Final.xlsx]Ops Data'!$A$8:$A$11 where it's missing a few \'s around the year and monthnum parts.

@VBasic2008, INDIRECT seems to work across linked workbooks if they remain  open, right?

@nkalvi Yes, that's true. But do you really want such half-functionalities in your workbook?

Thanks @VBasic2008, well I wouldn't :) I'll add an alternative using CHOOSE a bit later.

Since the constructed links will be used in multiple places, I would suggest using a named formula.

create the function, for example named rpt_link

with parameters: root_folder, year, and rng (lookup and return ranges)

we use the existing named values: monthnum, month, defectmonth


=LET(
    rpt_link, LAMBDA(root_folder, year, rng,
        LET(
            folder_sep, "\",
            year_folder, TEXTJOIN(folder_sep, , year, TRIM(CONCAT(monthnum, " ", month))),
            folder, TEXTJOIN(folder_sep, , root_folder, year_folder, "Defect Rate"),
            workbook, CONCAT("[", defectmonth, " Tracking Report - Final.xlsx", "]"),
            sheet, "Ops Data",
            MAP(rng, LAMBDA(r, CONCAT("'", folder, folder_sep, workbook, sheet, "'", "!", r)))
        )
    ),
    ranges1, rpt_link(
        "O:\Operational Excellence\Reporting\Metrics",
        2024,
        {"$A$8:$A$11", "$F$8:$F$11"}
    ),
    note, "Lookup with: XLOOKUP(3, INDIRECT(INDEX(ranges1, 1, 1)), INDIRECT(INDEX(ranges1, 1, 2)))",
    TOCOL(ranges1)
)

Here's the result of links:

Once you've verified the links, add the function rpt_link in Name Manager:
=LAMBDA(root_folder,year,rng, 
LET(folder_sep, "\",  year_folder, TEXTJOIN(folder_sep, , year, TRIM(CONCAT(monthnum, " ", month))),  
folder, TEXTJOIN(folder_sep, , root_folder, 
year_folder, "Defect Rate"),  workbook, CONCAT("[", defectmonth, " Tracking Report - Final.xlsx", "]"),  
sheet, "Ops Data",  MAP(rng, LAMBDA(r, CONCAT("'", folder, folder_sep, workbook, sheet, "'", "!", r)))))


Then it could be used like this in this workbook (and others by copying a sheet to the other workbook):
=LET(
    ranges1, rpt_link("O:\Operational Excellence\Reporting\Metrics", 2024, {"$A$8:$A$11", "$F$8:$F$11"}),
    XLOOKUP(Q29, INDIRECT(INDEX(ranges1, 1, 1)), INDIRECT(INDEX(ranges1, 1, 2)))
)


This works on my Mac (with my custom paths)
For INDIRECT to work, linked workbook needed remain open


CHOOSE
Depending on your use case, you could avoid using INDIRECT by using CHOOSE, for example to lookup links:
=LAMBDA(y,
    CHOOSE(
        XMATCH(TEXTJOIN("-", , y, month, monthnum, defectmonth), "2024-September-09.-07-2024"),
        'O:\Operational Excellence\Reporting\Metrics\2024\09. September\Defect Rate\[07-2024 Tracking Report - Final.xlsx]Ops Data'!$A$8:$A$11
    )
)(2024)


My god.  This is way beyond what I'm capable of following.  I cannot reply on indirect because I'd need 4-5 large workbooks open that other people are also needing to work with.  I got the big function to work, but don't understand how to alter it to get the choose to work instead of indirect.  I tried to break down the function but kept getting lost.  I'm really impressed, but could you help a little more and explain what is happening in that?  Why we can't just do a text join, or something.  Why does it need to be in a nested Let formula?  That thing is a monster to me.

@LaurenYork-Toenniges, my apologies for the long formula. I try to use variables to make it easy to create formulas and understand them. My answer is only a starting point; I could suggest a better formula if you could tell me how to build the links terms of various folders, workbooks and named ranges. I would still urge avoiding INDIRECT as many have complained about negative impact, especially with many/large files.

Oh no apologies needed, I'm just starting out in excel so I was way intimidated.  I will definitely have to not use indirect.  What exactly do you need for building the links terms of various folders, workbooks etc?  I could probably compile a list of each file path if that's what you mean.  I'm at the 'I know excel does a thousand things, so there has to be a better way" stage of learning excel, but it's been an uphill battle.  I am happy to provide anything you need beyond providing the actual files themselves since they are protected company data.  Filepaths etc I can share in this case.

@LaurenYork-Toenniges, I don't need the actual files, only the paths and ranges and how they're to be used in the existing/proposed formulas.

I'm so sorry it took so long to respond.  I was out sick.  Here are the paths:

for N29-41 in LS PIVOTS : =XLOOKUP(M41,'O:\Operational Excellence\Reporting\Metrics\2024\09. September\SLA[OPsSLAHistoricalDateRange September 2024.xlsx]Total Data'!$K:$K,'O:\Operational Excellence\Reporting\Metrics\2024\09. September\SLA[OPsSLAHistoricalDateRange September 2024.xlsx]Total Data'!$L:$L,"NA")

for N42: =XLOOKUP(M42,'O:\Operational Excellence\Reporting\Metrics\2024\09. September\SLA[OPsSLAHistoricalDateRange September 2024.xlsx]Total Data'!$F$20:$F$23,'O:\Operational Excellence\Reporting\Metrics\2024\09. September\SLA[OPsSLAHistoricalDateRange September 2024.xlsx]Total Data'!$I$20:$I$23)

for R29: =XLOOKUP(Q29,'O:\Operational Excellence\Reporting\Metrics\2024\09. September\Defect Rate[7-2024 Tracking Report - Final.xlsx]Ops Data'!$A$8:$A$11,'O:\Operational Excellence\Reporting\Metrics\2024\09. September\Defect Rate[7-2024 Tracking Report - Final.xlsx]Ops Data'!$F$8:$F$11)

Those are basically the general pattern for each sheet, with changes to ranges etc.  I may have to forgo this project because if I make it too complicated and something breaks in several months or a year or two down the line they need to be able to figure out how to fix it.  This team is a bit of a revolving door by design so I'd like to leave them with something that is robust and hard to break.

Thank you @LaurenYork-Toenniges. I completely agree with your assessment about how to proceed to have robust and manageable solution. Anyway, I'll work on this later to see how do it without INDIRECT.
